# Rstudio: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theano'

Tags: keras, rstudio, theano

I am trying to follow the basic tutorial on using keras from Rstudio: https://keras.rstudio.com/

I have successfully used keras before on this machine, directly from python, but now I want to use it with R.

When I do

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

Everything seems to work fine. But then when I try

```
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

I see:

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theano'

The tutorial says:

> The Keras R interface uses the TensorFlow backend engine by default.

I tried looking for a theano package but Rstudio tells me:

> package ‘theano’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

I am using Rstudio 1.1.463 on an iMac with macOs Mojave 10.14.1.

I originally found this problem with an anaconda installation which used python 2.7. I made a new anaconda installation using python 3.7 but that did not fix it. When I was using keras directly from python, I first was using theano, but later switched to using tensorflow.

Do I have some configuration wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your `keras.json` file somewhere in your user or home folder in a folder named `.keras` (that might be hidden).

There you will find a configuration line that should be: `"backend": "tensorflow"`

On Windows, it's in `c:\users\<username>\.keras\keras.json`